# jQuery toggled tr elements drift down page

Tags: jquery, html-table, webkit, toggle, slidetoggle

The gist of my problem is that I have a table that every even row is hidden, and visibility is toggled using an anchor on the row above. This works correctly, but in some browsers (Safari and Chrome) the tr below the one that just appeared moves down further than it should have.

If you keep toggling the hidden tr the next sibling drifts down the page.

Here is a bare bones code that shows this issue (requires jquery)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() { //document ready

   $('.details').hide();

   $('.show_hide').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('tr').next().slideToggle('slow');
   });


  }); //end doc ready
 </script>

 <style>
  table {
   width: 500px;
  }

  .main td {
   width: 33%;
  }
 </style>

 <table>
  <tr class="main">
   <td>Title</td>
   <td>Some Detail</td>
   <td><a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/Hide</a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="details">
   <td>
    Sed scelerisque, tellus non auctor pretium, felis massa vehicula sem, quis vehicula nulla dolor eget justo. Pellentesque porttitor aliquet metus a accumsan. Aenean luctus, lacus in tristique imperdiet, nulla ipsum dignissim massa, quis laoreet eros justo eu nibh. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam sed purus nisi, at venenatis tellus. Praesent id magna ac dui congue convallis. Duis sit amet arcu eu ipsum tincidunt fermentum. Praesent mollis, eros sit amet auctor iaculis, mi elit aliquet elit, at rhoncus elit urna nec magna. Vestibulum iaculis fringilla diam, in rhoncus tortor blandit id. Nam id leo eros, et posuere massa. Morbi fermentum egestas nisl, et pharetra urna convallis viverra. Maecenas id massa nulla. Pellentesque eget urna vel diam interdum sollicitudin sit amet in massa.
   </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="main">
   <td>Title 2</td>
   <td>Some Detail 2</td>
   <td><a href="#" class="show_hide">Show/Hide</a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="details">
   <td>
    Sed scelerisque, tellus non auctor pretium, felis massa vehicula sem, quis vehicula nulla dolor eget justo. Pellentesque porttitor aliquet metus a accumsan. Aenean luctus, lacus in tristique imperdiet, nulla ipsum dignissim massa, quis laoreet eros justo eu nibh. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam sed purus nisi, at venenatis tellus. Praesent id magna ac dui congue convallis. Duis sit amet arcu eu ipsum tincidunt fermentum. Praesent mollis, eros sit amet auctor iaculis, mi elit aliquet elit, at rhoncus elit urna nec magna. Vestibulum iaculis fringilla diam, in rhoncus tortor blandit id. Nam id leo eros, et posuere massa. Morbi fermentum egestas nisl, et pharetra urna convallis viverra. Maecenas id massa nulla. Pellentesque eget urna vel diam interdum sollicitudin sit amet in massa.
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

The above code seems to work fine in Opera and Firefox, but the issue mentioned above happens in Safari and Chrome. (Haven't tested in IE yet). This makes me suspicious that it is a webkit related issue.

Anyone else found the problem? Is there a workaround?

Comment: used your code and can't reproduce the problem, tesdted in Chrome and Safari, can you reproduce it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fzHug/1/ ?

Comment: If you google show hide tr jquery you'll find lots of references to weird things happening when trying to show hide tr's in various browsers.  However, I used your code, tested with jquery 1.4.3 and chrome 7.0.517.44 and did not experience your problem.  I tested in ie 8 and ff3.6 as well.  All browsers worked fine.  My suggestion is to try different methods instead of using slide toggle, try fade, and regular show/hide, or if you aren't using the latest jquery, upgrade.  Otherwise I would just suggest not hiding tr's... switch to li's and css =]

Comment: @Sebastian Patane Masuelli Oddly no, it doesn't happen in that fiddle. jQuery 1.4.4 or otherwise. Great tool though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to reproduce your problem in Chrome with jQuery 1.4.2, but not with 1.4.4. In fact, with 1.4.4, the table row doesn't animate at all -- instead it just toggles on and off (after a delay).

The behavior of `slideToggle` on table elements seems to be somewhat undefined. As a workaround, place a `<div>` around your `<td>` contents and call `slideToggle` on that instead:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <div class="details">
            Sed scelerisque...
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I am using 1.4.2 (in the jquery ui package) I'll give 1.4.4 a go and see if I see improvement

Comment: No improvement for me using 1.4.4, but it works by wrapping it in a div. Thanks.